# Iterating over each element in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I got a pandas DataFrame with a single column and a lot of data.

I need to access each of the element, not to change it (with apply()) but to parse it into another function.

When looping through the DataFrame it always stops after the first one.

If I convert it to a list before, then my numbers are all in braces (eg. [12] instead of 12) thus breaking my code.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

def go_trough_list(df):
  for number in df:
    print(number)

df = pd.read_csv("my_ids.csv")
go_trough_list(df)
```

df looks like:

```
   1
0  2
1  3
2  4
dtype: object
[Finished in 1.1s]
```

Edit: I found one mistake. My first value is recognized as a header.
So I changed my code to:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_ids.csv",header=None)
```

But with

```
for ix in df.index:
    print(df.loc[ix])
```

I get:

```
0    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
0    2
Name: 1, dtype: int64
0    3
Name: 2, dtype: int64
0    4
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

edit: Here is my Solution thanks to jezrael and Nick!

First I added `headings=None` because my data has no header.
Then I changed my function to:

```
def go_through_list(df)
    new_list = df[0].apply(my_function,parameter=par1)
    return new_list
```

And it works perfectly! Thank you again guys, problem solved.

Comment: change go_trough_list(df) to go_trough_list(df['column_name'])

Comment: if you would give us more details what do you want to parse, sample input data and expected output then we could probably find another solution where you wouldn't have to iterate through your data frame...

Comment: My input data are Ids. 
I want to create a list and insert additional data, which I get from another function for each id.

Comment: look at the Nick Brady's example  - it's exactly what you need, just apply __your__ function instead

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the index as in other answers, and also iterate through the df and access the row like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['column'])
```

however, I suggest solving the problem differently if performance is of any concern. Also, if there is only one column, it is more correct to use a [Pandas Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html).

What do you mean by parse it into another function? Perhaps take the value, and do something to it and create it into another column?

> I need to access each of the element, not to change it (with apply()) but to parse it into another function.

Perhaps this example will help:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([20, 21, 12])
def square(x):
    return x**2
df['new_col'] = df[0].apply(square)  # can use a lambda here nicely
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, by applying your code its working. But only with the square function.

My function needs an additional parameter, which is called 'color'. Its not part of the dataFrame.

Comment: Hi Ali, the function can be defined however you want. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with your function, but keep in mind what is essentially happening is mapping in python. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map .Please accept if I answered your question :) thanks

Comment: Quick search told me that I can parse arguments with newer pandas. It actually works now. Thank you very much.!

Answer (score 4):

You can convert column as `Series` [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
for x in df['Colname'].tolist():
    print x
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series( [1, 2, 3]),
                   'b': pd.Series( [4, 5, 6])})
print df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

for x in df['a'].tolist():
    print x
    1
    2
    3
```

If you have only one column, use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting first column:

```
for x in df.iloc[:,0].tolist():
    print x
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: pd.Series( [2, 3, 4])})
print df
   1
0  2
1  3
2  4

for x in df.iloc[:,0].tolist():
    print x
    2
    3
    4
```

This can work too, but it is not recommended approach, because `1` can be number or string and it can raise Key error:

```
for x in df[1].tolist():
    print x
2
3
4
```

Comment: My data has just a single column, so when I apply that code without ['Colname'] i get the error:  `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: What is `print df.columns` ?

Comment: With adding `headings=None` I get:  `NameError: name 'columns' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have one column named 'myColumn', and you have an index on the dataframe (which is automatically created with read_csv). Try using the .loc function:

```
for ix in df.index:
    print(df.loc[ix]['myColumn'])
```

Comment: My list looks like: 1 2 3 4, that is also my desired output.

But the program output is:

1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
1    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64
1    4
Name: 2, dtype: int64

Comment: Can you post some sample rows of the dataframe?